# Не верный port при запросе Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemotePort

Tags: c#, nginx, asp.net-core, .net-5

На сервере стоит iptraf-ng для сбора статистики трафика и проблема заключается в том что порт IP адреса клиента отличается от порта полученного с помощью Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemotePort.

Проксирование осуществляется с помощью Nginx и само приложение размещено на сервере в Docker контейнере, надеюсь кто нить с подобной проблемой сталкивался. В принципе понимаю что проблема в том что из за проксирования порт клиента меняется, но так и не нашел информации как захватить первичный порт по которому прошел первичный запрос к серверу.

Comment: А зачем вам вообще этот порт понадобился, почему это проблема?

Comment: Отслеживание использование трафика пользователей, иногда пользователи заходят из одной сети и у них может совпадать IP-адрес. А вот порт при подключение всегда уникальный.

Comment: ну так и следите тогда за подключениями, которые держит nginx, а не бэкенд